# Why does the first statement compile but not the second?

Tags: delphi

See code below. It is an AfterOpen event of a ClientDataSet.
Why does the second statement NOT compile?
The error message is: Undeclared identifier: 'LogChanges'
The third statement compiles.
Is the third statement correct, and equivalent to the first one?
If 'DataSet' cannot be used, why is it passed?

```
procedure TCTL_Configurator_form.cdsZonesAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  cdsZones.LogChanges                 := FALSE; // This line compiles
  DataSet.LogChanges                  := FALSE; // This line does NOT compile
  TClientDataSet(DataSet).LogChanges  := FALSE; // This line compiles
end;
```

Comment: Note that the 3rd option could fail at runtime with an Access Violation if the event is ever passed a `DataSet` that's *not* a `TClientDataSet` or descendant.

Comment: I mention the complier error on line three of my question.

Comment: afrazier, the event will only be called from the dataset where I originally doubleclicked to create it. Do you mean that the access violation could happen if the same event is called from other datasets as well? If so, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TDataSet` does not have a method `LogChanges`. It's introduced in `TClientDataSet`, which is why the third line compiles; you've typecast the `DataSet` to the more specific `TClientDataSet`. And as Anthony points out in a comment, the typecast will cause an access violation at runtime if the DataSet isn't actually a TClientDataSet or descendent of TClientDataSet - a better choice would be to use `(DataSet as TClientDataSet)` to check, or use an `if DataSet is TClientDataSet`.

The `AfterOpen` event is introduced in `TDataSet`, and it receives a plain old `TDataSet` as a parameter.

Comment: I use the type cast so the exact same statement can be used for other. datasets as well, thinking that might avoid future copy/paste errors when/if more similar datasets are added. Is typecasting a good or bad way to do this?

Comment: It's fine for other datasets that are descendants of `TClientDataSet`, Anders, although you'd be wise to use a *checked* type cast instead. That's the kind using the `as` operator. (And if you're really attaching this event handler to events for multiple objects, I'd advise giving the method a more generic name that doesn't look like it belongs to just one specific object.)

Comment: I think I might be unclear here. I am not attaching one single event to multiple clientdatasets. I have many similar clientdatasets and prefer to have identically coded events as far as possible. In the future when I need yet another, and do copy/paste, there will be less to modify. Can you give an example of a checked typecast applicable in this specific case?

Comment: @AndersJ: Instead of _TClientDataSet(DataSet).LogChanges_ use _(DataSet as TClientDataSet).LogChanges_

Comment: @Heartware: I said that in my answer.

Comment: Yes, but it seems like @AndersJ didn't catch on, so I spelled it out.

Comment: @AndersJ: I gave examples in my post - see the end of the first paragraph, beginning with *- a better choice would be to use*.